# Fail to upload local CSV file with fetch

Tags: javascript, html, csv, google-chrome, fetch

I'm trying to use fetch to open a .csv file, but i get this message:
Uncaught TypeError TypeError: Failed to fetch
I am using Visual Studio Code and Chrome there.
my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Read CSV File</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="output"></div>

<script>
// Function to fetch the CSV file
function fetchCSV(url) {
    return fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(csv => processData(csv));
}

// Function to process the CSV data
function processData(csv) {
    var rows = csv.split('\n');
    var output = document.getElementById('output');
    output.innerHTML = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var columns = rows[i].split(',');
        if (columns.length >= 3) {
            output.innerHTML += columns[2] + '<br>';
        }
    }
}

// Preload and process the CSV file
fetchCSV('Book1.csv'); // Replace 'example.csv' with the your CSV file
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Book1.csv is in the same folder of the file that holds the code.

Kind regards

I tried running in different browsers.
A different .csv file because I thought it was too big, the new file is smaller.

Comment: your code isn't uploading anything - it's downloading a CSV file from the "server" to the browser, is it not?

Comment: Yes, thanks for your answer, that’s what I am trying to do.

Comment: I solved, it seems that chrome doesn’t load upload a local file due security reasons, so I deactivated security snd I worked. Thanks

Comment: oh, you're not using a http server - yeah, that'll break browsers